# MVC: How to return to previous state of form

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a currently loaded form with different fields in it. Example I am on URL: https://localhost:44300/ where the form is currently displayed. However, once of the fields has a link beside it "View Full List" where in once I click on that it will redirect me to a different view and user can select one value from there.

View full list when clicked will be redirected to: https://localhost:44300/project/organisationfulllist/

[image]

Now, once I have selected from the displayed list in that view (radiobutton list), I will click on a [SAVE] button and it should redirect me back to my original form with URL https://localhost:44300/

My question is when I am redirecting to the original view, the previous inputs on several fields were reset. What I want is to preserve these inputs from user. Is there a way to sort of save the session of the previous form?

Comment: Save the user inputs in a cookie and then read them out when you return to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Save the information in the session once the user clicks "View Full List"

```
Session["formdata"] = formdata;
```

Then get it back when you open the form again

```
FormModel formModel = Session["formdata"] as FormModel;
```

Is it possible to not redirect when user clicks "View Full List" and keep the selection on the same page? On a pop-up or something.

Comment: Yes I am thinking of just fancybox? But I can's seem to display it in modal, it still displays in whole screen.

Comment: I posted my fancybox issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901051/mvc-cant-make-fancybox-work

Comment: Posted an answer to your other question. Can you flag this as a correct answer if it helped you change your approach? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901051/mvc-cant-make-fancybox-work/32906355#32906355